# How do I retrieve a user's activity on any page using Graph or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible, with suitable permissions granted by the user, to retrieve a user's activity on any Facebook page?

For example, if user X posts to their own wall, then adds a comment to a friend's wall, or comments on a photo, or even likes something on another user's Facebook page, is it possible for me (not user X) to retrieve all that activity from the user's activity log or the stream table?  And if so, is it possible to automate the process so that I can get a daily log of user X's Facebook activity, regardless of where that activity was?